# Which function does OpenAs_RunDLL finally calls under Windows 8?

Tags: function, winapi, windows-8, executable

I'm trying to use OpenAs_RunDLLW to let the user select application he wants to open specific file with. But I don't want to really launch anything, just to let the user select and remember his choise so I can then open the file with this program later. In Windows XP, Vista and 7 OpenAs_RunDLLW finally used to call ShellExecuteExW, so I could temporary put the int 3 opcode at the beginning of this function, catch the exception and get all parameters passed to ShellExecuteExW. This was good and really worked.

But under Windows 8/8.1 it seems that OpenAs_RunDLLW does not call ShellExecuteExW, since the breakpoint is never hit. The selected app is launched instead. So, my question is - **which API function does OpenAs_RunDLLW finally call to execute the program under Windows 8?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the shell now uses [`IAssocHandler::Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open the item.  However, you probably don't really *care* about that; what you want is a way to find out how to get the invocation handler.

For that, you want [`ShAssocEnumHandlers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762109%28VS.85%29.aspx), which takes a file name extension and returns an [association enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (that is, a function that will enumerate all the various applications that can open that extension).

Comment: Thank you, SHAssocEnumHandlers does provide an enumerator, but it lacks two following features:
1. I need to provide my own way to let the user select another app not presented in the list. Not a big problem though.
2. IAssocHandler returns the target app file name only, not a full command line. E.g. the target app is designed to be used with the "-open" command line switch - I won't get it.

Comment: @kde - IAssocHandler::Invoke (and IAssocHandlerInvoker::Invoke) don't necessarily create a process.  If they *do*, however, it looks like it ends up going directly through CreateProcess.

Comment: Try using [`AssocQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471.aspx) with the `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` flag to get the full command line for a given file extension.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: this way I'll get the default association command line only, but I want the user to choose which program he wants to use.
Eric Brown: I'll try to put breakpoint at CreateProcessW, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and later, use [`SHOpenWithDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of calling `OpenAs_RunDLL()`, and then use [`SHAssocEnumHandlers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762109%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out which handlers are registered and to invoke a particular handler when needed, instead of using `ShellExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you, SHOpenWithDialog fully eliminates the need to search for a procedure address within shell32.dll, but it introduces some incompatibility since it is not supported by Windows XP. And since it still cannot return the app selected, I really doubt of its benefit.

Comment: Regarding SHAssocEnumHandlers, please see my comment to the previous post.